# Keras logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [10240,151] and labels shape [1], sparse_categorical_crossentropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create a Unet for semantic segmentation.. I've been following this [repo](https://github.com/dhassault/tf-semantic-example)  that has the code from this [article](https://yann-leguilly.gitlab.io/post/2019-12-14-tensorflow-tfdata-segmentation/). I'm using the [scene parsing 150 dataset](http://sceneparsing.csail.mit.edu) instead of the one used in the article. My data is not one-hot encoded so I'm trying to use sparse_categorical_crossentropy for loss.

This is the shape of my data. x is RGB images, y is 1 channel annotations of categories (151 categories). **Yes, I'm using just 10 samples of each, just for testing, this will be changed when I can actually get it to start training.**

```
x_train shape:  (10, 32, 32, 3)
y_train shape:  (10, 32, 32, 1)
x_val shape:  (10, 32, 32, 3)
y_val shape:  (10, 32, 32, 1)
```

These are the first and last layer of the Unet.

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 32, 32, 3)]  0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
... other layers ...
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_23 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 32, 151)  453         conv2d_22[0][0] 
==================================================================================================
```

Or from the code:

```
input_size = (IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_CHANNELS) # 32x32x3
inputs = Input(shape=input_size)
...
output = Conv2D(N_CLASSES, 1, activation='softmax')(conv_dec_4)
```

The exact error I am getting it:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [10240,151] and labels shape [1]
         [[{{node loss/dense_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]]
```

I can see how the logits shape is `[32x32xSamples,Number_of_classes]` but why is the label shape just `[1]`?

I can not find a single search result of someone that has a label shape of `[1]` so here I am, posting a new question. What am I doing wrong and what do I need to do to fix this? Please ask if you need any other relevant info.

### Notes:

I would very much prefer to keep using sparse_categorical_crossentropy and not one-hot encode and use categorical_crossentropy.

Also here are my package and python versions:

```
$ python -V
Python 3.6.7

$ pip list
Package                  Version
------------------------ -------------------
absl-py                  0.12.0
astor                    0.8.1
astunparse               1.6.3
attrs                    21.2.0
cached-property          1.5.2
cachetools               4.2.2
certifi                  2021.5.30
chardet                  4.0.0
cycler                   0.10.0
dataclasses              0.8
dill                     0.3.3
flatbuffers              1.12
future                   0.18.2
gast                     0.4.0
google-auth              1.30.1
google-auth-oauthlib     0.4.4
google-pasta             0.2.0
googleapis-common-protos 1.53.0
grpcio                   1.34.1
h5py                     2.9.0
idna                     2.10
importlib-metadata       4.4.0
Keras                    2.4.3
Keras-Applications       1.0.8
keras-nightly            2.5.0.dev2021032900
Keras-Preprocessing      1.1.2
kiwisolver               1.3.1
Markdown                 3.3.4
matplotlib               3.3.4
numpy                    1.19.5
oauthlib                 3.1.1
opencv-python            3.4.2.16
opt-einsum               3.3.0
Pillow                   8.2.0
pip                      21.1.2
promise                  2.3
protobuf                 3.17.2
pyasn1                   0.4.8
pyasn1-modules           0.2.8
pyparsing                2.4.7
python-dateutil          2.8.1
PyYAML                   5.4.1
requests                 2.25.1
requests-oauthlib        1.3.0
rsa                      4.7.2
scipy                    1.5.4
setuptools               57.0.0
six                      1.15.0
tensorboard              1.14.0
tensorboard-data-server  0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit   1.8.0
tensorflow               1.14.0
tensorflow-datasets      1.3.2
tensorflow-estimator     1.14.0
tensorflow-metadata      1.0.0
termcolor                1.1.0
tqdm                     4.61.0
typing-extensions        3.7.4.3
urllib3                  1.26.5
Werkzeug                 2.0.1
wheel                    0.36.2
wrapt                    1.12.1
zipp                     3.4.1
```

## Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
"""Minimal Example"""
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

IMAGE_HEIGHT = 4
IMAGE_WIDTH = 4
IMAGE_CHANNELS = 3
MASK_CHANNELS = 1
N_CLASSES = 151

x_train = np.array([[[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]],
                   [[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]],
                   [[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]],
                   [[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]],
                    ])
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=0)

y_train = np.array([[[0], [9], [1], [1]],
                   [[2], [1], [3], [6]],
                   [[1], [4], [1], [1]],
                   [[1], [1], [1], [8]],
                    ])
y_train = np.expand_dims(y_train, axis=0)

x_val = np.array([[[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]],
                 [[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]],
                 [[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]],
                 [[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]],
                  ])
x_val = np.expand_dims(x_val, axis=0)

y_val = np.array([[[0], [9], [1], [1]],
                 [[2], [1], [3], [6]],
                 [[1], [4], [1], [1]],
                 [[1], [1], [1], [8]],
                  ])
y_val = np.expand_dims(y_val, axis=0)

inputs = Input(shape=(IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_CHANNELS))
conv_enc_1 = Conv2D(4, 3)(inputs)
output = Conv2D(N_CLASSES, 1, activation='softmax')(conv_enc_1)

unet = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)

unet.summary()

unet.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy())
unet.fit((x_train, y_train), epochs=10, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, verbose=1, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

Comment: can you make a minimal reproducible code?

Comment: I can try, give me a few minutes.

Comment: added the minimal reproducible example

Comment: there appear to be some mistakes in your example, your model outputs 2x2x151 and ground truth is 4x4x1 and `model.fit` should be called as `model.fit(x, y)` and not `model.fit((x, y))`. After fixing those issues, the code runs without error. Can you show your original code?

Comment: omg I think it was just those extra (), I can't remember why I was using a tuple. give me a minute to confirm on the original code

Comment: removing those parens from the original code fixes the issue, thank you! I'll mark this is solved

Comment: By the way using softmax with one class makes no sense (think about what value it produces).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have 151 classes, what makes you think I have 1? In the example I have only a few random ones of the 151 labels. Did you spot a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Dominik Ficek's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11083136/dominik-ficek)

```
unet.fit((x_train, y_train))
```

should have been:

```
unet.fit(x_train, y_train)
```